# Flutter: ListView disable scrolling with touchscreen

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, disable

Is it possible to let a ListView only be scrollable with the ScrollController and not with the touchscreen?

Comment: There is an field in ListView `physics = NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`; Now you can implement it base on some condition

Comment: Can you talk more about what you've tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the [NeverScrollableScrollPhysics class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html) will do this:

> **NeverScrollableScrollPhysics class**
>
> Scroll physics that does not allow the user to scroll.

Answer (score 259):

Inside ListView widget, use

```
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

Answer (score 53):

You may add just `primary: false` inside your ListView Widget

Defaults to matching platform conventions. Furthermore, if the primary is false, then the user cannot scroll if there is insufficient content to scroll, while if the primary is true, they can always attempt to scroll.

For more, check out [Official Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/physics.html)

Answer (score 22):

Conditional statement for enable and disable scrollview.

```
physics: chckSwitch ? const  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Answer (score 19):

Worked for me

```
 ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
...
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem?

Answer (score 5):

what about NestedScrollView ?

```
            bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomAppBar(),
            body: Container(
              child: NestedScrollView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                controller: _scrollViewController,
                headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                  return <Widget>[
                    buildSliverAppBar(innerBoxIsScrolled),
                  ];
                },
                body: _buildBody(context),
              ),
            ),
          );
```

it's working for me