# How to scroll only the scrollbar not the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to scroll only the scrollbar not the screen in the flutter

So I have this problem, I want to work on the scrollbar scrolling only not the entire screen of this.

Thank you!

here is the sample of my code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MySecondRoundedAppbar("TEST"),
      body: Scrollbar(
        
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
        
        child: Column(
          children: [
            
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  
                 
                  Expanded(
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text("test"),
                      color: color4,
                      onPressed: () {
                        
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text("test"),
                      color: color4,
                      onPressed: () {
                       
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: ListView disable scrolling with touchscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477809/flutter-listview-disable-scrolling-with-touchscreen)

Comment: sad to say, it didn't

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet creates a scrollable ListView in Flutter with a Scrollbar and a ScrollController that synchronizes the thumb position with the list's scroll position. Here's a breakdown of what each part does:

1. **ScrollController**: This controller manages the scroll position of the ListView.
2. **Scrollbar**: It's a widget that provides a scrollbar to indicate the current scroll position. The `thumbVisibility` parameter sets whether the scrollbar thumb is always visible or not.
3. **ScrollConfiguration**: It defines the custom scrolling behavior for the ListView. In this case, it enables the scrollbar and ensures that the scrolling physics are always scrollable.
4. **NotificationListener**: This widget listens to scroll notifications from the ListView. When a scroll update notification is received (`ScrollUpdateNotification`), it uses the `_scrollController` to jump to the updated scroll position indicated by `notification.metrics.pixels`.
5. **ListView**: This is the scrollable list widget. It uses the same `_scrollController` for its controller property and can contain a list of children widgets.

Overall, this code constructs a ListView with a Scrollbar and ensures that when the user interacts with the scrollbar, the ListView's scroll position is updated accordingly. Additionally, it synchronizes the ListView's scroll position when manual scrolling occurs within the ListView itself.

### Example Code here

```
ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

Scrollbar(
      controller: _scrollController,
      thumbVisibility: true,
      child: ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollbars: true,
        ),
        child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
          onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
            if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
              _scrollController.jumpTo(notification.metrics.pixels);
            }
            return false;
          },
          child: ListView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            primary: false,
            children: <Widget>[
              // Your code
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```